Last humans guard earth from underground bunkers connected by video chat
Name that SciFi film:
Last humans guard earth from within underground, secret, globally distributed bunkers connected by a video chat system (one per bunker).  A timed automated system requires them to prove that they're still alive (a red button?).  If they were to fail to check in, the earth blows up with the assumption that the alien invasion succeeded and the perspective that if we can't have Earth, no one can.

I think this is an episode of The Outer Limits called "Dead Man's Switch", which was first broadcast in April, 1997.  Here's part of the IMDb plot summary:

Ben Conklin is a last-minute replacement for a long-term isolation assignment. He's advised by General James Eiger that some time ago, long range probes identified an alien force heading directly for Earth. In the event they should lose any battle with the aliens they have arranged for a self-destruct mechanism to destroy all life on the planet. The system will automatically fire giving Conklin 30 seconds to hit the kill switch. Eiger tells him that if they succeed, they will dig him out in about a year's time; if they don't appear, he should assume the worse. Conklin learns that there are three others in different locations around the world who can also stop the doomsday device from firing.


Somehow immediately thought about Outer Limits when reading that, seemed to fit the interesting SciFi-plots they had.
